# Intuitive explanation why only one direction of the Borel Cantelli Lemma requires stochastic independence

Tags: probability

I wonder whether there is an intuitive explanation why one part of the Borel Cantelli Lemma requires stochastic independence and the other one does not. I understand the proofs but I do not have an intuitive grasph why it should be like that.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but note that the "(all) independence assumption" can be substantially weakened to pairwise independence (and even weaker) for the 2nd BC lemma to hold.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A hint is the following example.

If you set the events $A_n$ all to be equal to the same event $A_1$ then clearly you lose independence.
Now in this case the event "$A_n$ is infinitely often true" ($A_n \,i.o.$) has the same probability of $A_1$ true.
Moreover, if $P(A_1) = p \in (0,1)$ the series $\sum_n P(A_n)$ clearly diverges, but $P(A_n \, i.o)=p$.
Instead, the same trick (that introduces dependence between the marginal events $A_n$) does not work if we want that the series $\sum_n P(A_n) < \infty$.